# weird logs when using tab completion on rosrun

Tags: rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recently, I get some weird log messages when i try to complete the package name (or exec name) for rosrun using the tab key:

```
rosrun ro[OPTION]...: command not found
PATTERN: command not found
by: command not found
-i: command not found
The program 'and' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install and
PATTERN: command not found
PATTERN: command not found
PATTERN: command not found
PATTERN: command not found
No command 'use' found, did you mean:
 Command 'nse' from package 'ns2' (universe)
 Command 'ase' from package 'python-ase' (universe)
 Command 'fuse' from package 'fuse-emulator-sdl' (universe)
 Command 'fuse' from package 'fuse-emulator-gtk' (universe)
 Command 'muse' from package 'muse' (universe)
use: command not found
obtain: command not found
ignore: command not found
No command 'force' found, did you mean:
 Command 'forge' from package 'snap' (universe)
 Command 'zforce' from package 'gzip' (main)
force: command not found
No command 'force' found, did you mean:
 Command 'zforce' from package 'gzip' (main)
 Command 'forge' from package 'snap' (universe)
force: command not found
a: command not found
suppress: command not found
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

If I enter a fully qualified name rosrun is still working! Also auto completion is still working for roslaunch. Any ideas what could cause this??

Under Ubuntu 14.04.2 ROS indigo....

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204753/weird-logs-when-using-tab-completion-on-rosrun/) by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7555 on 2015-03-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By comparing my during the installation modified `~/.bashrc` with `/etc/skel/.bashrc` using `diff` I found that I accidentally inserted some characters behind a `grep` `alias` in the `~/.bashrc`:

That's how it was, which caused the autocompletion error:

```
alias grep='grep --color=auto'accidentally inserted characters
```

That's how it now is and should be:

```
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
```

Apparently the autocompletion for `rosrun` somehow uses this alias which caused the failure...

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2015-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1